# Using tags for user-set UX details

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, tags, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm using `acts_as_taggable_on` for tagging items across my system so that they're easily searchable.

Now I have a UX problem: I'm noticing lots of places where users choose certain minor states (for example, closing a one-time help box or moving to the next javascript-run step in a given page). We have here situations that are both too minor/numerous/dynamic/fast-changing to be put into a database table (imagine having to migrate with every UX change!), and that there is a need to persist some of these choices beyond the session.

In this case, is there anything wrong with using tags to store these simple decisions? For example, `user.set_tags_on(:ui, "closed_index_help")` or `user.set_tags_on(:ui, "tutorial_1_done")`, then showing/hiding these elements in the future by looking at the user's `ui_list`.

Are there drawbacks to this I'm not considering or is this a prudent way to go?

Answer (score -1):

Another way might be to store the information in the SESSION. You will of course have to migrate the session information to be stored in the DB rather than the cookie, but at least that way - you only have to retrieve the session once.